# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) during sqlite3 query execution with NDK

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk

I have a table in `SQLite` with around 1600 rows and each row contains `HTML` Page to show in a `WebView`. I have to implement search like that, that `HTML` tags should be ignored while searching. For that, I imported `sqlite3` library and made my own User Defined Function called `strip_text` which ignores tags using `regex`.

```
static void strip_text(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv) {
    if(argc == 1) {
        //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "TAG", "inside strip_text");
        char *result = (char *) sqlite3_value_text(argv[0]);
        std::string text(result);
        std::regex my_regex("REGEX");

        if (!text.empty()) {
            text = std::regex_replace(text, my_regex, "");
            sqlite3_result_text(context, text.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            return;
        }

    }
    sqlite3_result_null(context);
}
```

My function for query is as follows.

```
std::list<int> get_page_list(std:: string q) {
    std::string query = "SELECT page_no FROM bahar_e_shariat WHERE LIKE('%" + q + "%', strip_text(page_text))=1";
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "TAG", "%s", query.c_str());


    std::list<int> pages_list;

    sqlite3 *db;
    //Open database
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "TAG", "Opening database");
    int rc =     sqlite3_open("/data/data/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat/databases/Books.db", &db);
    //It'll be good to check 'rc' for error(s).


    rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "strip_text", 1, SQLITE_ANY, NULL, &strip_text, NULL, NULL);

    sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL);

    while(1) {
        int s = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        if(s == SQLITE_ROW) {
        pages_list.push_front(sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0));
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "TAG", "Found in %d", sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0));
        } else if(s == SQLITE_DONE) break;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return pages_list;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Now the problem is that it starts searching and after searching around 8 to 9 records, the app crashes with error

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7f84630ff0 in tid 28988 (Thread-6559)
```

Referring to some answers, I have added `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` but it didn't work.

I can't figure out the problem. Can anybody tell me what's happening here?

**UPDATE**

When I test it on Infininx Note 3 Pro, it's not working but it's working on Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: why do you want NDK for that?

Comment: I need user defined function and it can only be implemented using NDK

Comment: `"user defined function"`? how the user can "define function"? in C?

Comment: I am sorry, I should be clear. It is to be used in `sqlite` as you can see my query. It states `SELECT page_no FROM bahar_e_shariat WHERE strip_text(page_text) LIKE %search_term%`

The function `strip_text` cannot be made without using NDK

Comment: so is it a big problem to keep both versions (html / plain text) in two different columns if you have just 2k rows?

Comment: It is only a single book. There are around 1500 books.

Comment: so keep plain text in a separate database, built every time you open a new book, with [fts](https://blog.xojo.com/2014/03/14/full-text-search-with-sqlite/) it should be quite small

Comment: Hopefully you got past this error, but if you're not seeing a stack trace below the fatal signal line you should turn off logcat filtering by selecting 'No filters' from the dropdown.